# Fill in all the blanks using a single homophone

Tags: wordplay, homophone

Fill in the blanks using a single homophone word.

Robert ___ , the ___ doctor employed by ___ Corporation, makers of "ADD-ON-___ ", went to ___ for a business meeting and enjoyed a delicious meal of ___ with his clients.

I asked this question on another site but got no solution.

Comment: You say "a single homophone word" - Do you mean a homograph? I.e. same spelling different meaning?

Comment: No. Different or same spellings, different meanings but same pronounciation like Eight and Ate

Comment: Did you make this puzzle yourself?

Comment: Yes. I know the rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

> Robert **SOWELL**, the **SOLE** doctor employed by **SOUL** Corporation, makers of "ADD-ON-**SOLE**", went to **SEOUL** for a business meeting and enjoyed a delicious meal of **SOLE** with his clients. — *Dr Sowell, the only doctor who works for a company that produces quick-repair kits for shoes, ate a flatfish when seeing his business partners in Korea*.
>
>  Yes, these are three occurrences of "sole", but each has a different meaning. I'm guessing the last name of the employee and the name of the corporation. There is a football player named [Robert Sowell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Sowell) and I can imagine that the W isn't really pronounced as in Powell, but with another pronunciation of the o. The company might as well be a sole corporation consisting of a single employee. In that case, it's a bit silly to say Dr. Sowell is the sole doctor, so perhaps he is a soul doctor.
>
>  (I've made the company name Soul because I hadn't used that homophone yet. My first idea was to use it in soul doctor, because I had mistakenly assumed is was a colloquial name for a psychiatrist. Another word I haven't used is Sol, which at least in America seems to be an acceptable [homophone](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Sol). That offers a further opportunity for either of the two names.)

Comment: Wonderful job. I was starting ot think about hints but you got it.